# Section permissions are ignored when linking to an entry

Tags: redactor, sections, permissions

Users with permissions to limited sections can still “link to an entry” in any section from within the WYSIWYG (Redactor) editor.  I'm using Craft 2 with a Rich Text (Redactor) field.

Is this a bug or is there a way to fix this?

Here's some screenshots of the flow of what I'm talking about:

[image: Go to Entries and the sections are limited but if you link to an entry, you can see all sections]